# JQueryMobile Datepicker and new framework

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, datepicker

I was using [JQueryMobile's experiment Datepicker](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/) for a while and it worked in the old framwork. Yesterday i changed the framework to latest one and found that it breaks the layout of the Datepicker when I click outside.

[image: broken layout]

Has anyone ecountered same problem?? how did you over come it?? it means datepicker will not be supported in the latest framwork??

My code goes as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css" /> 
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>



    <script>
  //reset type=date inputs to text
  $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = true;

  });

  $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });

  </script>
  <script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>
</script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <label for="date">Date Input:</label>
        <input type="date" name="date" id="date" value=""  /> 

        <div id='datepicker'></div>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use this one:

[Jquery Mobile datepicker](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/)

I have not checked whether this works with 1.1, but it's kept up to date and provides a ton of features.

Comment: But it doesn't show the week number in the UI. Dats the biggest issue with datebox plugin.

Comment: in latest version it supports week number too <3

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same problem and I just changed the date picker API. 
Use this one it will give every thing you want, like the UI like iOS, Android, jQuery Mobile, mode, modal etc. to set along with jQuery code.

[jQuery mobile datepicker](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/)

The problem never comes after using this.

Comment: But I need a calender view :( not a picker view. also I should show week number too which is not supported even in DateBox.

Comment: If you'd like to display the week number, use the "headerText", where you can pass in a function (where you figure out the week number) and it will display that in your modal window.

Comment: You can get a calendar view with the Mobiscroll Calendar (and you can even mix it with a time scroller for instance)

Answer (score 2):

Find this code in ***jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js***
just below the updateDatepicker();

```
$( ".ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-btn", dp ).each(function(){
var el = $(this);
// remove extra button markup - necessary for date value to be interpreted correctly
el.html( el.find(".ui-btn-text").text() );   
});
```

replace

```
el.html( el.find(".ui-btn-text").text() );
```

with

```
el.text( el.text() );
```

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

after a lot of search on Internet, especially comparing datebox and jqueryui datepicker (mobiscroll and mobipick are no good to me as i'am looking for a calendar view, i got to the point where i decided to use ui datepicker for few reasons :

- i use it from longtime, i know it well enough
- i needed the beforeShowDay (event if it is certainly possible to have similar fonction using datebox and events/callbacks) to customize days with classes
- i needed a header with possibilities to change month and year (also possible in datebox)
- with this experiment i already had a datepicker with a jquerymobile feel & look

I used it with :

- jquery 1.8.3
- jquery mobile 1.2.0
- jqueryui datepicker 1.8.21 ([get it from here](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/06/jquery-ui-1-8-21/))

using datepicker with more recent versions breaks the layout on month/year change.

from [here](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Mobile-Themed-DatePicker), i got the files i needed. I used several answers i found on different stackoverflow questions, to make the following changes :

- no change on jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css
- jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js new code :

  ```
  (function ($, undefined) {

  //cache previous datepicker ui method
  var prevDp = $.fn.datepicker;

  //rewrite datepicker
  $.fn.datepicker = function (options) {

  var dp = this;

  //call cached datepicker plugin
  var retValue = prevDp.apply(this, arguments);

  //extend with some dom manipulation to update the markup for jQM
  //call immediately
  function updateDatepicker() {
      $(".ui-datepicker-header", dp).addClass("ui-body-c ui-corner-top").removeClass("ui-corner-all");
      $(".ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next", dp).attr("href", "#");
      $(".ui-datepicker-prev", dp).buttonMarkup({ iconpos: "notext", icon: "arrow-l", shadow: true, corners: true });
      $(".ui-datepicker-next", dp).buttonMarkup({ iconpos: "notext", icon: "arrow-r", shadow: true, corners: true });
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar th", dp).addClass("ui-bar-c");
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar td", dp).addClass("ui-body-c");
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar a", dp).buttonMarkup({ corners: false, shadow: false });
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar a.ui-state-active", dp).addClass("ui-btn-active"); // selected date
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar a.ui-state-highlight", dp).addClass("ui-btn-up-e"); // today"s date
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-btn", dp).each(function () {
          var el = $(this);
          // remove extra button markup - necessary for date value to be interpreted correctly
          // only do this if needed, sometimes clicks are received that don't require update
          // e.g. clicking in the datepicker region but not on a button.
          // e.g. clicking on a disabled date (from next month)
          var uiBtnText = el.find(".ui-btn-text");
          if (uiBtnText.length)
              el.html(uiBtnText.text());
      });
  };

  //update after each operation
  updateDatepicker();

     $( dp ).on( "click change", function( event, ui)
  {
  $target=$(event.target);
  if(event.type=="click" && ($target.hasClass("ui-datepicker-month") || $target.hasClass("ui-datepicker-year")))          
      event.preventDefault();
  else
      updateDatepicker( event);
  });

  //return jqm obj 
  if (retValue) {
      if (!retValue.jquery) return retValue;
  }
  return this;
  };

  })(jQuery);
  ```

i use on() instead of click event and i preventDefault on click on month/year select menu.

And i use it this way :

```
$form
    .trigger( "create" )
    .find( "input[type='date'], input:jqmData(type='date')")
    .each(function()
        {
        $(this)
            .after( $( "<div />" ).datepicker(
                {
                altField            : "#" + $(this).attr( "id" ),
                altFormat           : "dd/mm/yy",
                showOtherMonths     : true,
                selectOtherMonths           : true,
                showWeek            : true,
                changeYear          : true,
                changeMonth         : true,
                beforeShowDay       : beforeShowDay
                }));
        });
```

with beforeShowDay being a function returning an array (see jqueryui datepicker manual).

It works for me this way and i now i just need to add events to only show calendar when date input got focus.

[A link to jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/idukad/1/)

Answer (score 0):

*copy of answer elsewhere :*

I worked on updating the jquery ui datepicker to latest versions of jquery , jqueryui and jquery mobile so for jq1.9.1 jqui 1.10.2 and jqm 1.3.0. I prefered to leave as is my previous answer so you can see how it evolved.

the changeMonth and changeYear dropdown needed special care to work (unstylying was frequent)

here it is how i updated the experimental jqueryui datepicker for jqmobile :

[js bin code snippet](http://jsbin.com/ukelis/1)

You can link to the datepicker script instead of the whole jqueryui package.

The readonly prop prevents the keyboard to appear on ios

It is just a tweak of the datepicker to make it work on jqm, the goal would be to be able to override the _generatehtml function of datepicker widget and being able to give as input te jquery mobile theme to use. So you'll not need that whole bunch of addClass and avoid unnecessary DOM manipulation

I only tested for ios 6 (iphone, ipad) and desktop (chrome, firefox, safari), let us know about other tests.

Hope it helps as mush as needed it :)

here is all the code separated in html, js and css :

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>Jqueryui 1.10.2 datepicker Integration in jquery mobile 1.3.0 and jquery 1.9.1 by aureltime</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css">
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>  
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>jQuery UI's Datepicker Styled for mobile adapted by Aureltime</h1>      
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form action="#" method="get" id="form">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="date">Date:</label>
                <input type="date" name="date" id="date" value=""  />
            </div>      
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
//reset type=date inputs to text
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = true;

$("#form").trigger("create");
$( document )
  .on( "pageinit", function(){

$("#date")
    .prop("readonly", "true")
    .on("click", function(){
$input=$(this);
$next=$input.next();

if($next.hasClass("hasDatepicker"))
  $next.hide();

$input
      .hide()
      .after( $( "<div />", {   id  :   "datepicker_"+$input.attr("id")}).datepicker(
        {
          altField          : "#" + $input.attr( "id" ),
          altFormat         : "dd/mm/yy",
          defaultDate       : $input.val(),
          showOtherMonths   : true,
          selectOtherMonths : true,
          //showWeek        : true,
          changeYear        : true,
          changeMonth       : true,
          //showButtonPanel : true,
          //beforeShowDay   : beforeShowDay,
          onSelect          : function( dateText, inst)
          {             $("#datepicker_"+$input.attr("id")).hide();
$input.show();
          }
        }));
    });
        });


(function($, undefined ) {

    //cache previous datepicker ui method
    var prevDp = $.fn.datepicker;

    //rewrite datepicker
    $.fn.datepicker = function( options ){

        var dp = this;

        //call cached datepicker plugin
        prevDp.call( this, options );

        //extend with some dom manipulation to update the markup for jQM
        //call immediately
        function updateDatepicker(event){

          $( ".ui-datepicker-header", dp ).addClass("ui-body-c ui-corner-top").removeClass("ui-corner-all");
            $( ".ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next", dp ).attr("href", "#");
            $( ".ui-datepicker-prev", dp ).buttonMarkup({iconpos: "notext", icon: "arrow-l", shadow: true, corners: true});
            $( ".ui-datepicker-next", dp ).buttonMarkup({iconpos: "notext", icon: "arrow-r", shadow: true, corners: true});
            $( ".ui-datepicker-calendar th", dp ).addClass("ui-bar-c");
            $( ".ui-datepicker-calendar td", dp ).addClass("ui-body-c");
            $( ".ui-datepicker-calendar a", dp ).buttonMarkup({corners: false, shadow: false}); 
            $( ".ui-datepicker-calendar a.ui-state-active", dp ).addClass("ui-btn-active"); // selected date
            $( ".ui-datepicker-calendar a.ui-state-highlight", dp ).addClass("ui-btn-up-e"); // today"s date

            if(typeof event != "undefined")
                {
                var classe= $(event.target).attr("class");
                //alert(classe);
                }
          $( ".ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-btn", dp ).each(function(){
                    var el = $(this);
                    var buttonText = el.find( ".ui-btn-text" );
                    // remove extra button markup - necessary for date value to be interpreted correctly
                    if(buttonText.length)
                        el.html( el.find( ".ui-btn-text" ).text() ); 
                    });
        //      }

        $( dp )
            .off()
            .on( "click", updateDatepicker)
            .find("select")
            .on( "change", function(event){updateDatepicker(event);});
        }

        //update now
        updateDatepicker();

        //return jqm obj 
        return this;
    };
})( jQuery );
```

**CSS**

```
div.hasDatepicker{ display: block; padding: 0; overflow: visible;  margin: 8px 0; }
.ui-datepicker {  overflow: visible; margin: 0; max-width: 500px;  }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header { position:relative; padding:.4em 0; border-bottom: 0; font-weight: bold; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next { padding: 1px 0 1px 2px; position:absolute; top: .5em; margin-top: 0; text-indent: -9999px; }

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev { left:6px; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next { right:6px; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title { margin: 0 2.3em; line-height: 1.8em; text-align: center; }
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select { font-size:1em; margin:1px 0; }
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month-year {width: 100%;}
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month, 
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year { width: 49%;}
.ui-datepicker table {width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; margin:0; }
.ui-datepicker td { border-width: 1px; padding: 0; text-align: center; }
.ui-datepicker td span, .ui-datepicker td a { display: block; padding: .2em 0; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; border-width: 0; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; }

.ui-datepicker-calendar th { padding-top: .3em; padding-bottom: .3em; }
.ui-datepicker-calendar th span, .ui-datepicker-calendar span.ui-state-default { opacity: .3; }
.ui-datepicker-calendar td a { padding-top: .5em; padding-bottom: .5em; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a custom datetime picker effective for android and iphone flip (both date and time in two flips) hope it will help

https://github.com/ngethe/jQM-DateBoxNgethe